# Bhakti Siddhanta Saraswati Thakur's Opinions

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, bhakti, gaudiya-vaishnavism, ramakrishna

Is there any evidence that shows that Bhakti Siddhanta Saraswati Thakur (founder of Gauriya Mat) was critical/not critical of Ramkrishna Paramhamsa, Omkaranath Thakur, and Prabupad Bijoy Krishna Goswami? Citation from Bhakti Siddhanta Saraswati Thakur's work will help.

Comment: According to [**Śri Bhaktisiddhānta Vaibhava**](https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/278-sri-bhaktisiddhanta-vaibhava-pdf/)by Bhakti Vikāsa Swami, Bhakti Govinda Thakur(father of Bhakti Siddhanta Saraswati) met Ramkrishna Paramahamsa personally at Mr. Nrsimha Datta’s home. He was invited to **test** Shri Ramakrishna.

Comment: You can read the story in the chapter *Ramakrishna Mission* on page 1009 of pdf(won't personally "recommend" you to read it though as its full of criticism and objective bias and does nothing but sow seeds of hatred in the heart of reader which is exactly the opposite of what Gaudiyas try to "preach")....But i Hope this helps!

Comment: @Rāmachandra Thank you

Comment: Srila BhaktiSiddanta Saraswati Thakur's(BSST) father's name was Bhaktivinod Thakur. In Sri Vrindavan, there is a Gaudiya Math established at the bhajan sthal of Vijay Krishna Goswsmi, his personal murti is still worshiped by the Gsudiya Math devotees. BSST considered Ramakrishna mission as heratics, as in the garb of sannyasis, they did not follow in principle the rules of vedic dharma, like avoiding eating meat, smoking etc.Ramkrishna was a householder, but he gave sannyasa to Vivekananda etc, this is just not posdible as a householder cannot give sannyasa because only a sannyasi can give it